# Extract text with regex between two words in sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a table named TABLE and this has a column named MESSAGE. This column has the following values:

```
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXTORA-06512
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXT1ORA-O6512
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: NO data availableORA-06512
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20001: errorORA-06512
```

I want to use an **Oracle sql** query to parse the data and get a column named Error_code with the error code and an Error_message  with the message between the first ORA and the second ORA.

An expected outcome:

```
Error_code  Error_message
ORA-20000   SAMPLETEXT
ORA-20000   SAMPLETEXT1
ORA-01403   NO data available
ORA-20001:  error
```

I used the following query:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, 'ORA-[0-9]+') AS Error_Code,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '(?<=ORA-[0-9]+: ).*(?<=ORA)', 1, 1, 'n') AS Error_Message
FROM TABLE
```

with return results:

```
Error_code  Error_message
ORA-20000   
ORA-20000   
ORA-01403   
ORA-20001
```

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, 'ORA-[0-9]+: (.*?)(ORA|$)', 1, 1, 'n', 1)`?

Comment: It works as expected for all the cases!

Comment: But I guess everyone believes you need a non-regex approach

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be a regex solution, old `substr + instr` combination will perform better on large data set.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXTORA-06512' from dual union all
  3     select 'returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXT1ORA-O6512' from dual union all
  4     select 'returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: NO data availableORA-06512' from dual union all
  5     select 'returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20001: errorORA-06512' from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select col,
  8    substr(col, instr(col, 'ORA', 1, 1),
  9                instr(col, 'ORA', 1, 2) - instr(col, 'ORA', 1, 1)
 10          ) result
 11  from test;

COL                                                                           RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXTORA-06512        ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXT
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXT1ORA-O6512       ORA-20000: SAMPLETEXT1
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: NO data availableORA-06512 ORA-01403: NO data available
returning: -1 -> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20001: errorORA-06512             ORA-20001: error

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start from the last occurence of **:** by **`[^: ]`** and take the part until the end **`+$`** such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, 'ORA-[0-9]+') AS Error_Code,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '([^: ])+$') AS Error_Message
  FROM "TABLE"
```

provided the data model for the column is the same throughout the table

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference.

For *Error_Code*, use a *match pattern*.

```
(?=ORA-\d+).+?(?=:)
```

And, for *Error_Message*, use a *capture pattern*.

```
ORA-\d+:\s+(.+)ORA
```

Comment: Oracle [doesn't support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multilingual-Regular-Expression-Syntax.html#GUID-B03DEEAC-3F9E-4BFD-89D5-F481EA391D7C) lookarounds.